# Tunneling to redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I am new to redshift. Currently, I am able to create a redshift cluster and connect it through SQL Workbench but I am looking forward to tunnel my redshift cluster doing `ssh` from my MAC terminal. I did some research and able to create an ec2 instance with same VPC ID and subnet group which I am using to create my Redshift cluster with. I have already installed psql on my ec2 instance as well. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong when I use psql command to connect to redshift :

```
psql -h my redshift endpoint -p 5439 -d database name -U user -c " my query "
```

it gives me error psql: could not translate host name "my redshift endpoint" to address: Name or service not known

Comment: Please show the command you are using to tunnel to the EC2 instance. It should involve using `ssh -L` to forward a remote port to a local port.

Comment: yes I am using  here is the command "ssh -I "test.pem" -L 5439:redshiftendpoint:5439 ec2-user@ec2instance.compute.amazonaws.com"

Answer (score 5):

The first step is to tunnel to the EC2 instance using `ssh`, with a command that forwards a local port to a remote port:

```
ssh -i KEYPAIR.pem -L 5439:REDSHIFT-ENDPOINT:5439 ec2-user@EC2-PUBLIC-IP
```

Where:

- *KEYPAIR.pem* should be the name of the keypair used to access the EC2 instance
- *REDSHIFT-ENDPOINT* is the DNS name of the Redshift endpoint
- *EC2-PUBLIC-IP* is the IP address of the EC2 instance

This command says:

- Create an ssh connection using the keypair
- Forward any traffic sent to local port 5439 to the remote machine, then have the remote machine send that traffic to `REDSHIFT-ENDPOINT:5439` (substitute your endpoint for *REDSHIFT-ENDPOINT*)

Then, you can connect to Redshift on `localhost:5439` as if it were running on your own computer. That traffic will be sent to the remote machine, which will send it to `REDSHIFT-ENDPOINT:5439`.

For example, if you want to use `psql` to connect to Redshift, use:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U <username>
```

Comment: Do I have to change any setting in psql or ec2 instance. As I am still getting same issue with what you have suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what happens when you perform each step, including how long it takes to respond. For example, when you run `ssh`, it probably will probably appear to hang. This is okay! You should then use a separate Terminal session for `psql`. I can't help you unless you provide more information about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

try `psql -h localhost -p 5439 -d -U -c " my query "` or `psql -p 5439 -d -U -c " my query "`, you can't use switch `-h` without an argument, which is `localhost` by default if you don't use it

Comment: sorry, i did not see i forget to mention i am using my redshift endpoint after "-h"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John Rotenstein on giving me insight, I was actually missing the Inbound rule associated with my security group to only allow traffic coming from redshift private IP. Both of my ec2 instance and redshift were in the same VPC so was supposed to use private instead of public IP. Also forgot to put ssh public key of redshift in the ec2 authorized_key file. Once I did that it worked.